# C# Use the same variables for several strings

Tags: c#, string

Can i use the same variables in several cases without writing them multiple times?
e.g.

```
switch(a)
{
    case 1:
        ans = string.Format("someString {0}, {1}, {2}", var1, var2, var3);
    case 2:
        ans = string.Format("anotherString {0}, {1}, {2}", var1, var2, var3);
    case 3:
        ans = string.Format("thirdString {0}, {1}, {2}", var1, var2, var3);   
 }
```

can I write the variables var1, var2 and var3 in one place only?
thanks.

Comment: Depending on the version, you could use something like a local function.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

So only the format is changing while you want to insert the same values in each?

Then only select the format in your `switch` and do the string.Format once after it.

```
string fmt="";
switch(a)
{
    case 1:
        fmt = "someString {0}, {1}, {2}";
    case 2:
        fmt = "anotherString {0}, {1}, {2}";
    case 3:
        fmt = "thirdString {0}, {1}, {2}";   
 }
 ans = string.Format(fmt, var1, var2, var3);
```

Comment: Yes, this is because the code won't assign value to `fmt` if the variable `a` is not 1, 2 or 3, and you cannot use variable that not initialized in C#. So, use `default` instead of `case 3`, or declare `fmt` like `string fmt = null`.

Comment: I have added a default value of an empty string, as I suspect the string.Format will not like a null

Comment: This doesn't matter, because it seem that anyway `a` will be 1, 2 or 3. So you can use `default` instead of `case 3`, too.

Answer (score 1):

I would wrtie a `Dictionary<int,string>` let code more clear. then just put once `var1`,`var2`,`var3`

```
Dictionary<int, string> dict = new Dictionary<int, string>();
dict.Add(1, "someString");
dict.Add(2, "anotherString");
dict.Add(3, "thirdString");
string result = string.Empty;

if (dict.ContainsKey(a))
    result = string.Format("{0} {1}, {2}, {3}", dict[a], var1, var2, var3);
```

**EDIT**

thank for @mjwills suggest

`TryGetValue` would be faster than `ContainsKey` because `ContainsKey` need to do twice search getting the value, but `TryGetValue` just once

```
Dictionary<int, string> dict = new Dictionary<int, string>();
dict.Add(1, "someString");
dict.Add(2, "anotherString");
dict.Add(3, "thirdString");
string ans = string.Empty;
string key = string.Empty;

if (dict.TryGetValue(a, out key))
    ans = string.Format("{0} {1}, {2}, {3}", key, var1, var2, var3);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var temp = string.Format(" {0}, {1}, {2}", var1, var2, var3);

switch (a)
{
    case 1: ans = "someString" + temp; break;
    case 2: ans = "anotherString" + temp; break;
    case 3: ans = "thirdString" + temp; break;
}
```

---

Shorter and less readable alternative in Visual Studio 2015 or above:

```
if ((uint)--a < 3)
    ans = $"{new[] { "someString", "anotherString", "thirdString" }[a]} {var1}, {var2}, {var3}";
```